# Vapor 2 OR conditional not working on request type check

Tags: swift, logical-operators, vapor

Trying to allow HTTP `method.get` and `method.delete` to be missed in a request check. but it's failing.

```
func respond(to request: Request, chainingTo next: Responder) throws -> Response {
    if request.method != .get || request.method != .delete {
        guard let contentType = request.headers["Content-Type"], contentType == "application/json" else {
                    return try Response(status: .badRequest, json: JSON(node: ["reason": "Invalid data"]))                  
        }
    }
    return try next.respond(to: request)
}
```

Expecting to not allow `.get` or `.delete` to pass through.

Current result is that it goes straight through to invalid when either `.get` or `.delete` to show `invalid data`. It looks like the || operator is being ignored and I can't figure out why.

Comment: I think you meant && instead of ||

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the AND (`&&`) operator. With the way your code is currently written, it follows thus:

- A `GET` request comes from client and enters `respond` method.
- We get to the `if`-statement.
- Check the request method is not equal to `.get`. It *is* equal, so we move to the next case.
- Check the request method is not equal to `.delete`. It *is not* equal, so the statement passes.
- We run the code in the `if`-statement.

Using the `&&` operator will fail if either statement is false, whereas the `||` operator will fail if *both* statements are false.

```
if request.method != .get && request.method != .delete {
    guard let contentType = request.headers["Content-Type"], contentType == "application/json" else {
        return try Response(status: .badRequest, json: JSON(node: ["reason": "Invalid data"]))                  
    }
}
```

**Note:** You don't need the comma after `.get`. I honestly don't know what it does or if it even makes a difference.